# how to check for any carry generated while adding std_logic_vector using operator overloading?

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to add two std_logic_vectors using the notation given below:-

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity adder is
port( a:in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    b:in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    o:out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
end adder;

architecture Behavioral of adder is

begin
o<=a+b;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: How would you like the carry to be noted? Do you want a warning or would you like it to be saved somewhere? Also, do you specifically want to have operator overloading?

Comment: Yes, I want to save it. But that has been answered by @Morten Zilmer. Thanks.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to generate the result with carry, and then split that afterwards, like:

```
architecture Behavioral of adder is
    signal c_o : std_logic_vector(o'length downto 0);  -- Result with carry
    signal c   : std_logic;  -- Carry only
begin
    c_o <= ('0' & a) + b;  -- Result with carry; extended with '0' to keep carry 
    o <= c_o(o'range);     -- Result without carry
    c <= c_o(c_o'left);    -- Carry only
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: I think the OP wants an overloarded plus operator

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. The carry is not saved, but it's being reported that there was an overflow.

```
function "+" (Add1: std_logic_vector; Add2: std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is
    variable big_sum: bit_vector(Add1'LENGTH downto 0);
begin
    big_sum = Add1 + Add2;
    assert big_sum(Add1'LENGTH) = 0
      report "overflow"
      severity warning;
    return big_sum(Add1'LENGTH-1 downto 0);
```

Of course you'll need to define a new package and also include that package in your already existing file.

Answer (score -2):

```
o<=std_logic_vector(unsigned(a)+unsigned(b))
```

Although I suggest you use unsigned/signed on your ports (and have a clock cycle of latency).

If you want the carry

```
o_with_carry <= std_logic_vector('0'&unsigned(a)+unsigned(b));
o_carry <= o_with_carry(o_with_carry'high);
o <=  o_with_carry(o'range);
```

Comment: Carry is silently lost when doing addition based on original length, since result will have length of arguments, thus without room for any carry.

Comment: I tried using unsigned in my code, but the color of 'unsigned' won't change, I tried using numeric_std.all also but nothing happened. If the color of unsigned is not changing then it means that it is not a keyword.

Comment: In continuation to above comment:- Then how should I define unsigned ports or signals?

Comment: unsigned is a key word in in ieee.numeric_std. unsigned is also defined in STD_LOGIC_ARITH. You should be using ieee.numeric_std over std_logic_arith

Comment: unsigned ports are declared exactly the same way as std_logic_vector just replace std_logic_vector with unsigned

Comment: [why-library-numericstd-is-preferred](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.com.au/2010/03/why-library-numericstd-is-preferred.html)